# i have taken the get dependency in flutter still when i try to run it shows the following error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

- 'GetMaterialApp' is from 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.3.8/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'rtlguageguages'.
  (rtlguageguages.contains(Get.locale?.languageCode)

Comment: Are you still using "GetMaterialApp" somewhere within your code?
If not, try to run "flutter clean" before building your app.

Comment: i have tried it quite at times

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`import 'package:get/get.dart';`

not

`import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';`

Comment: still not working same problem  showing

Comment: I don't know well this problem. Pls try to reboot your pc and delete getX pub and install again.